# Filtering for Quic Client Hello packets with tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump, packet-sniffers, packet-capture

I am able to filter for Client Hello messages for TLS on TCP with the following:

`(tcp[((tcp[12] & 0xf0) >> 2)] = 0x16) && (tcp[((tcp[12] & 0xf0) >> 2) + 5] = 0x01)`

> https://www.baeldung.com/linux/tcpdump-capture-ssl-handshake

What filter can I use to achieve the same for Quic packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered this isn't possible with Quic as the the payload which contains the TLS handshake data is protected.

See:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9001#section-5.
Specifically section 5.2 related to initial packets.

The initial packets can be 'unencrypted' easily as long as you know the version specific hard coded salt value. But as far as I can tell this is something that can only be done after the packets have been captured (not *as* they are being captured).